# Angular 2 project does not work on Safari 5.7.1

Tags: angular, typescript

I am currently working on Angular 2. I need to run my projects on multi-browsers. When i tried in Safari, the project did not open in the Safari browser.

Safari version 5.7.1 which is i used.

I tried to uncomment the polyfill `import 'intl';` and run the npm `npm install --save intl`.

And also i was uncommented the following ployfills:

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

I am getting error as TypeError: Type error in script.bundle.js and Assertion failed: (Anonymous function).

Please help me to resolve. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As per the angular documentation minimum version of safari is 7.check out this [Browser support and polyfills guide.](https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html)

Comment: Yes, i checked that. But is there no another way to work on Safari 5.7.1?

Comment: I am not sure but you can search for pollyfill  for Safari